# Friendly_id creating duplicate slugs for multiple objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

My Rails build contains no pathnames. The application consists of two main objects: `collections` and `items`. So if I have a link: https://foo.com/foo, this could potentially identify either a collection or an item. The difference is made clear within the context and UI flow throughout the application.

My question: is there a way to have the Friendly ID gem generate unique slugs by seeing if a slug has already been taken by another object? I understand you can generate candidates so that friendly ID will not duplicate a slug for a given object, but I need friendly ID to check both existing collection slugs and item slugs before generating a new slug.

I hope that didn't sound too confusing. To re-word more concisely: is there a method available for friendly ID to check for slugs in multiple objects before generating a new slug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE** This is all untested, just working from docs and reading the source code.

You could inherit the **FriendlyId::SlugGenerator** class, and override the **available?** method to check for the existing records in the opposing model:

```
class CrossModelSlugGenerator << FriendlyId::SlugGenerator

    def available?(slug)
      if (@scope.class == "Item::ActiveRecord_Relation")
         # Search for collections with this slug and return false if they exist.
      elsif (@scope.class == "Collection::ActiveRecord_Relation")
         # Search for items with the this slug and return false if they exist.
      end

      # Otherwise do a normal slug check
      !@scope.exists_by_friendly_id?(slug)
    end

end
```

You can see the full code of the SlugGenerator class here:

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slug_generator.rb

Then you would have to tell the Friendly ID configuration to use that class instead.  Create an initializer in *config/intitializers/friendly_id.rb*:

```
FriendlyId.defaults do |config|
    config.slug_generator_class = "CrossModelSlugGenerator"
end
```

Try that out and see if it works out for you.  Again, I haven't tested any of it, but it seems like it should work out.

**EDIT** - You may need to wrap the class in the FriendlyId module like this:

You might need an include somewhere, possibly in your class definition.  Also, try wrapping the class into the FriendlyId module, so maybe something like this:

```
include "friendly_id"

module FriendlyId
  class CrossModelSlugGenerator << SlugGenerator
    ...
  end
end
```

With this change, you may also need to explicitly specify the module in the config class name:

```
FriendlyId.defaults do |config|
    config.slug_generator_class = "FriendlyId::CrossModelSlugGenerator"
end
```

Comment: This looks very promising and I will check this out first thing tomorrow morning and respond back to you. Thank you Jocko!!

Comment: Unfortunately, my application is unable to find the 'slug_generator_class'. Not sure why this is an issue, I'm using version 5.1.0 of the gem, and indeed using 'slugged' in my model: `extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]`

Comment: Updated the original answer with some variations in the approach, see if they work out for you.

Comment: You rock! It looks like there may be a couple ways to do this, but your method works great. I also tried out adding various slug candidates and if conditions to look through my item titles first before choosing a new slug for a given collection. Thank you very much for your informed and helpful answer!

Comment: `slug_generator_class` throws `undefined method` and using the `CrossModelSlugGenerator` throws `undefined method new for CrossModelSlugGenerator`:(